# How to responsively group rows, then columns in a bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a responsive web layout based on bootstrap. These are my two layouts:

[1A] [1B] [1C]

[2A] [2B] [2C]

[3A] [3B] [3C]

This is the layout for small screens.

[1A]

[1B]

[1C]

[2A] [3A]

[2B] [3B]

[2C] [3C]

For the small screen, I have a box around the horizontal groups ( 2A & 3A, 2B & 3B etc.). However, on large screens, I would like the items grouped vertically, so all the A's are in a box, all the B's are in a box etc. How do I do this, as the tags need to skip several sections as the HTML is written. Please see my code below. How would I do this?

```
<div class="container-fluid PageView text-center">
    <div class="row Page2">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="glyphicon-ring"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn glyphicon-bordered"></span>

            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="glyphicon-ring"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-bordered"></span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="glyphicon-ring"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone glyphicon-bordered"></span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
                        <h2><strong>Title 1</strong></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
                        <p class="lead">Text1</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
                        <h2><strong>Title 2</strong></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
                        <p Text 2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
                        <h2><strong>Title 3</strong></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
                        <p class="lead">Text 3</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

## EDIT

Using this code, I get the following result:

```
@media (min-width:769px){ /*use a value for your breakpoint*/
  .Page2 > *{border:5px solid white; background:#3DBEAF; border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; }
  .Page2 > *:nth-child(-n+3){border-bottom:0; }
  .Page2 > *:nth-last-child(-n+3){border-top:0;}
}
```

[image: Result]

How do I make sure only the outside 4 corners are rounded? Also, any ideas why there is a line down the middle of the block?

Comment: Why `container-fluid` inside `container-fluid` ?

Comment: @NenadVracar Sorry, that was where I copied the code and took out unnecessary bits, I have edited.

Comment: So on large screens you want icons vertically in one line and same for title and text not like as it is now https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/152/, is that it?

Comment: @NenadVracar No, that actual layout is correct. I want to draw a box vertically around each column ( all three elements ), but only on the large screen layout.

Comment: And on small width you want to keep that layout, as it is now in fiddle when you resize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a border around all of them and then target the first three/last three to customize the bottom/top border.

```
@media (min-width:769px){ /*use a value for your breakpoint*/
  .Page2 > *{border:1px solid #999;}
  .Page2 > *:nth-child(-n+3){border-bottom:0;}
  .Page2 > *:nth-last-child(-n+3){border-top:0;}
}
```

*updated code after comment*

```
@media (min-width:769px){ /*use a value for your breakpoint*/
  .Page2 > *{border:5px solid white;background:#3DBEAF;}
  .Page2 > *:nth-child(-n+3){
    border-bottom:0;
    border-top-left-radius:10px;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
  }
  .Page2 > *:nth-last-child(-n+3){
    border-top:0;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
  }
}
```

---

**Updated demo**

```css
@media (min-width: 769px) {
  /*use a value for your breakpoint*/
  .Page2 > * {
    border: 5px solid white;
    background: #3DBEAF;
  }
  .Page2 > *:nth-child(-n+3) {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  }
  .Page2 > *:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid PageView text-center">
  <div class="row Page2">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="glyphicon-ring">1A <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn glyphicon-bordered"></span>

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="glyphicon-ring">1B <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-bordered"></span>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="glyphicon-ring">1C <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone glyphicon-bordered"></span>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
            <h2><strong>2A Title 1</strong></h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
            <p class="lead">3A Text1</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
            <h2><strong>2B Title 2</strong></h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
            <p class="lead">3B Text 2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
            <h2><strong>2C Title 3</strong></h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
            <p class="lead">3C Text 3</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What kind of sorcery is this. +1 from me.

Comment: Will this work for a coloured background also? Just trying to get my head around what you are doing. +1 from me too - thanks!

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards if you mean different color for each column, then not as-is. but the idea is that you can use the `nth-child` and `nth-last-child` selectors to target the elements you want and apply the relevant styling. If you have problems applying the logic to colors post more details and i can look at it.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Thanks. I only need them to be all the same colour, which I have now done, however, I would like to round the corners, [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IfE5o.png) is what I have so far. I would like for only the outside corners of each block to have a radius. I will add my version of your code to the question. How do I do this?

Comment: the `:nth-child(-n+3)` rule targets the top row, while the `:nth-last-child(-n+3)` targets the bottom row. Apply the rounded corners in those rules instead of the `*` which targets all the blocks.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Awesome, thank you very much - really neat solution! On a side note, any ideas what is causing that very thin white line running under the glyph row?

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards i do not see it on my machine (*windows*) browsers (*Firefox, Chrome, IE*)

Comment: Hmmm, I am using Chrome, it disappears when I make my browser, I can see it when my window is around 1110px wide x 670px.